# Integration of f(x) where f(x) is x in binary, used as a decimal

Tags: definite-integrals, binary

> Define $f(x)$ when $x$ $\in [0,1]$ as $x_2$ ($x$ base 2) considered as a decimal value.
>
> Therefore, $f(0.75) = 0.11$, and $f(0.25) = 0.01$.
>
> Compute $\int_0^1f(x)dx$.

[image: Plot of f]

To do this, I figured that the answer might be $0$ because integrals aren't defined by the value at a point, and the graph shows its discontinuity. I also tried using a program, and I got $0$. Is this the correct answer? Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: How can the integral be $0$? The function is positive everywhere, and $f(x) \ge 0.1$ in the second half of the interval, so the integral must be at least $0.1 \cdot 0.5 = 0.05$.

Comment: Here is a picture of the graph. Note that the top is a little above 0.1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXOvy.png To be clear, I don't include (1,1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's why zero can't be right.  You can see $f(x) \geq 0.1$ on $[0.5,1.0)$.
So $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx \geq (0.1)(0.5) = 0.05$.

Also, $f(x) \geq 0.01$ on $[0.25,0.5)$, $f(x) \geq 0.1$ on $[0.5,0.75)$, and $f(x) \geq 0.11$ on $[0.75,1)$.  So
$$
    \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx \geq (0.01)(0.25) + (0.1)(0.25) + (0.11)(0.25) = (0.22)(0.25) = 0.055
$$
Keep going.  Then try to generalize.

Let $\chi_n(x)$ be the $n$th digit of $x$ in its binary expansion.  Notice that
$$
    \int_0^1 \chi_n(x)\,dx = \frac{1}{2}
$$
That is, half of the numbers in $[0,1]$ have this digit zero, and half have it one.
Also,
$$
    f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi_n(x)}{10^n}
$$
Integrating term-by-term, we have
$$
    \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1/2}{10^n} = \frac{1/20}{1-1/10} = \frac{1}{18} = 0.05555\dotsc
$$
You will need to make sure that integrating the series term-by-term is justified.  That should be OK because $0 \leq \chi_n(x) \leq 1$.  By the Weierstrass $M$-test, the series converges uniformly.

Comment: I get what you're saying in a intuitive sense. In regards to my program, considering that the graph is discontinuous, would it be possible to approximate this using a Riemann sum?

Comment: @JohnLou The four term sum (adding in a first 0 term) $0*0.25+0.01* 0.25+0.1*0.25+0.11*0.25$ appearing in Matthew's answer *is* a left-hand Riemann sum approximation of the integral.

Comment: Thanks. It turned out to be a coding error when converting into binary.