# Integration of $f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is $x$ in not in base $10$, used as a decimal

Tags: definite-integrals, soft-question, binary

Recently, I asked this question: [Integration of f(x) where f(x) is x in binary, used as a decimal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2255564/integration-of-fx-where-fx-is-x-in-binary-used-as-a-decimal). Please see this question for more details regarding the exact operations.

Following the answer to my question, I began to think about how to think about this intuitively. Using @MatthewLeingang's answer, we see a Riemann sum method of finding this area. Rather than use the complicated math he used, I looked at it this way.

If I have $2$ rectangles, then my "depth" is $log_2(2) = 1$. Therefore, I will go out until the first place after the decimal point. My summation will be $0.5(0.0 + 0.1)$. With depth $2$, I have $0.25(0.0 + 0.01 + 0.1 + 0.11)$.

Continuing this on, we see that we practically just exhaust all the possible combinations given a depth. Now, when we add up the inside of those parentheses, we notice that the value at each place value is the same. For depth $2$, it is $0.25(0.22)$, and for depth $4$, it is $0.0625(0.0001 + ... + 0.1111) = 0.0625(0.8888)$, etc.

Now, notice that all of these can be simplified down: $0.0625(0.8888) = 0.5(0.1111) \approx 0.25(0.22) = 0.5(0.11)$. From here, it's rather easy to notice that the answer is probably just $0.055555555...$ or $\frac{1}{18}$.

Next, looking at base $3$, I'll skip ahead a little. Basically where I got to is that each place value, once simplified, has the digit $3$. Looking at our expansion of combinations that we did in the previous base, we see that each digit can be either $0, 1$, or $2$, each equally. So, our equation is $\frac{1}{3}(0.333333333...)$.

Expanding this to base $n$, our value of the integral ends up being $\frac{1}{n}(0.\underline{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$ $\underline{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$ $\underline{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}})...$ which simplifies to $0.\underline{\frac{(n-1)}{2}}$ $\underline{\frac{(n-1)}{2}}$ $\underline{\frac{(n-1)}{2}}...$. Note that here the terms carry. This definition obviously works for base $2$, but trying it out for base $10$, we get $0.\underline{\frac{9}{2}}$ $\underline{\frac{9}{2}}$ $\underline{\frac{9}{2}}...$, or $0.\underline{4.5}$ $\underline{4.5}$ $\underline{4.5}...$. This simplifies to $0.\underline{4}$ $\underline{9}$ $\underline{9}$ $\underline{9}$ $\underline{9}...$ or basically $0.5$ which, is the $\int_0^1f(x)dx$ where $f(x) = x_{10}$ or $x$ base $10$, which is just $x$.

Something that I believe is true here is that the area for a given base $n$ can be found as the arithmetic mean of the area for two other bases $n+a$ and $n-a$. For example, if we take $f(x)$ using base $6$, we can take the average of the base $2$ and base $10$, which we already know: $\frac{1}{18} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{5}{9}$, which, I'm pretty sure, is the area under base $6$.

Sorry for the long backstory, but I did have a couple of questions to throw out there.

1) Is the integral even valid for bases higher than 10? @MarkS. on the previous question posted a picture that showed the basics of the graph. Using the formula that I mentioned before would give us values for these integrals, but I'm not sure how/if they could be represented.

2) Are there any other interesting patterns to be noted with this idea? Any applications elsewhere?

Looking back, this is a really long question, so thanks in advance!

EDIT: Turns out that for a given base $n$, $A =  \frac{n-1}{18}$.

Comment: In fact, the answer to the question you linked can be directly generalized to work for all bases, even those greater than 10. Converting digits greater than 9 to base 10 automatically becomes analogous to 'carrying' in that answer's method. Is that what your first question is asking?

Comment: By the way, great question! I'm sure there are some interesting things here.

Comment: @shardulc I think I did generalize it to all bases, but my first question is more about whether the concept makes sense. I'm not sure if I can represent a base 11 value as a base 10 value, because there's going to be a new character. I don't face this challenge with values base 10 and under.

Comment: OK. If you have a base 16 number, say, like $0.1B$, then that would be interpreted in base 10 as $\frac{1}{10} + \frac{11}{100} = 0.21$. Notice that the B carried 'backwards' to increase the 1 to a 2. This works for any base, perhaps involving a chain of such backward carries.

Comment: Oh, I see. I forgot that the denominator would change. That pretty much answers my first question, then. I'd like to point out that the integral with respect to base 19, is therefore 1. Based on the last rule that I proposed, it would suggest that the base 1 representation (all zeros) + the base 19 representation divided by 2 would give us $\frac{1}{2}$, suggesting that the base 19 integral is 1. Is there anything else you noticed? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I wonder why people would integrate in bases other than 10.

Comment: Wish I knew ... So far I've still only seen this type of problem once - in this situation. I'm not sure if there are any applications so if you find something that'd be cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same spirit as the calculation for binary, for base $3$ the digits are $0,1,2$, so the average digit is $1$.  Then in the $n$th place past the decimal you get a contribution of $\frac 1{10^n}$ and the integral is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{10^n}=\frac 19$.  For any base $b$ below $10$, the average digit is $\frac {b-1}2$ and the sum will be $\frac {b-1}{18}$.  This works whether you keep $b$ in the place it belongs or carry the leading digits of $b$ (when the digit is greater than $10$) to previous columns in the expansion.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't catch that it diverges.

Comment: I'm revisiting this problem after a while, I don't think I understand why the series would diverge if the average digit is $10$. Would that not just result in a value of $1.111$? Thanks!

Comment: @JohnLou:  You are correct.  I have updated the answer.